# Will PHP load all files references in a page?

Tags: php, class, caching, memcached

I am working on a cache class, I would like to be able to set and get cached items from 5 different storage mediums.  Memcache, APC cache, file cache, sessions, cookies.  Maybe even a 6th (database could be added as a 6th).

My goal is to make this flexible enough that I can use it in the future on many projects very easily (portable).  I also would like to be able to set/get cache items all from calling 1 set method and 1 get method.

Below is the code I have started so far which will allow me to do that.  In my switch block I am not sure if I should put all the code for that cache type there or have it call another method, or have each switch block item call a completley new class/object.

I am thinking that if I put each cache system in it's own class file, then my autolaoding will not need to load as much code for this if only a couple of the cache types is used on a page.  I am not sure though, using autoloading for my class files, would it still load 6 different class files in the code below or would it ONLY load the files that the switch needs.  For example if a page only uses the sessions cache, would my switch below only load a session class file or would PHP automaticly load all the files?  It is hard to test because if I put something to try to test it in my code, then it will definately load all the files.

Please give me advice and I do not want to use a framework, I am trying to learn not use an existing framework.

```
/**
* Set a key/value to cache system.
*
* @param   string        type of cache to store with
* @param   string|array  keys, or array of values
* @param   mixed         value (if keys is not an array)
* @return  void
*/  
public function set($type, $keys, $value = FALSE, $options_arr)
{
    if (empty($keys))
        return FALSE;

    if ( ! is_array($keys))
    {
        $keys = array($keys => $val);
    }

    // Pick our Cache system to use
    switch ($type) {
        case "memcache":
            echo "Cache item to memcache";
            break;

        case "apc":
            echo "Cache item to APC";
            break;

        case "session":
            echo "Cache item to Sessions";
            foreach ($keys as $key => $val)
            {
                // Set the key
                $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
            }
            break;

        case "cookie":
            echo "Cache item to Cookie";
            break;

        case "file":
            echo "Cache item to File";
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading only occurs when you try to reference a class which does not exist. That is, when that line is executed. It doesn't parse through the file to find all the possible classes - it's strictly as needed.

Comment: One way you could test it would be to put some sort of output into the `__autoload` function, so you can track each time it has been called.

Comment: yeah I just didnt know if it would have the file loaded just incase I call it.  I still have soo much to learn about classes and objects.  Maybe I should have this code in a main cache class and then have like a memcache class that extends this class

Comment: One problem with autoloading is that it slightly defeats the purpose of the APC opcode cache because autoloaded files can't benefit from the same opcode caching as they are requested at runtime.  There's no workaround so everybody has to deal with it (unfortunately).